# How to merge duplicate pages in a shopping cart?

Tags: duplicates, seo, opencart, shopping-cart, sitemap.xml

I use Opencart as my shopping cart and each product has 3 different way to access and it seems to be 3 duplicate content , theses pages are the same product :

```
 example.com/iphone12
 example.com/cellphone/iphone12
 example.com/apple/iphone12
```

how to tel google that these are the same product and are not duplicate content?
(every three URLs generate in sitemap.xml seperately)

Answer (score 0):

I should use the canonical link in my each 3 pages head .

```
<link href="https://www.example.com/iphone12" rel="canonical" />
```

more details [here](https://moz.com/learn/seo/canonicalization)